# SQL server: Max time with no TIMESTAMP

Tags: sql-server

How can I drop the time from a query when tring to get the max time.

```
Select (CONVERT(date,DATEADD(d,-7, GETDATE()) , 101)) as FromDate, max(Creation_Date) as ToDate 
from [UserRatings_all]  
WHERE ([UserID] = 'blah') 
group by userid
```

Gives me:

```
FromDate    ToDate
2013-09-19  2013-09-21 02:27:34.000
```

I need to drop that toDate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To return just the date as a string
     CONVERT(CHAR(10),MAX(creation_date),101)